# How to use summary-level Formula to calculate percentage when a field is a specifc value?

Tags: reporting, custom-reports, report-builder

How to use summary-level Formula to calculate percentage when a field is a specific value?

For example:
[image]

Where the percentage represents = a number of order of pizza / total orders for that month.

Jan = 2/10 orders were pizza for ID 1,

Feb = 1/10 orders were pizza for ID 2

I've already grouped my instance such that it is formatted as above. So grouped rows by Customer ID and columns by purchase month.

I tried creating a summary formula but I can't seem to figure out how to specify a specific value so that I can create the formula for summing all the order='pizza' divided by total orders.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In a report builder scenario you may need to add a filter (so orders are filtered to a specific type) or build multiple reports where the dataset is filtered down to a specific order type.

Comment: @nbrown I tried the filter way but that won't give me the percentage out of total orders but just the order='pizza'

Answer (score 1):

You can use PARENTGROUPVAL(summary_field, grouping_level) funtion for this problem to calculate total count of Pizza Orders